# Script is being executed manually but not at root crontab on suse 10 sp2

Tags: shell, suse

I added this script as root user to the root cron as below, but it is not working, what could be wrong? it is suse 10 sp2 is maybe a different the way for adding crontabs?

```
$Crontab -e 
35 11 * * * /home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile/packaging_cdr_script3.sh
```

## --the script:

```
drFEP1a:/home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile # more packaging_cdr_script3.sh
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
FILE="cdr_backup_${DATE}.tar.gz"
TEMPFILE="tempfile_${DATE}"
DESTINATION=/root/patrick_temp/
ERROR="Tar file has not been created nor removed the source call records"

find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD*' -type f -ctime 1 -print > ${TEMPFILE}
tar -czf ${FILE} -T ${TEMPFILE}
if [ -f $FILE ];
then
        mv cdr_backup* ${DESTINATION}
        number=$(more ${TEMPFILE} |wc -l)
        echo "$DATE:Number of files backed up-->$number ">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
else
echo "$DATE:$ERROR">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
fi
```

## Permissions

```
drFEP1a:/home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile # ls -lhrt packaging_cdr_script*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 547 Jan 21 11:21 packaging_cdr_script3.sh
```

## SUSE

```
drFEP1a:/home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile # more /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/news/bin
MAILTO=root 
#
# check scripts in cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly, and cron.monthly
#
-*/15 * * * *   root  test -x /usr/lib/cron/run-crons && /usr/lib/cron/run-crons>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish, `chmod 777` is a serious security error. Remove write permission for group and others.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Does the script not get executed at the appropriate time?  Does it get executed but generate some unexpected error?  Is there a specific reason why you included the contents of `/etc/crontab` above?  I don't think that file is relevant to the issue ...

Comment: It will execute in your home directory. By the looks of things, you are expecting otherwise?

Comment: Guys the problem is that when adding this script to the suse root crontab to be executed at some time every day, nothing is happening, i want to know if i have to put the script under other location/folder or so it can be executed by the cron automatically because as i said, it is not being executed at the time set in the cron above. by other side this script is working when i do directly sh packaging_cdr_script3.sh at the script location

Comment: Have you tried `35 11 * * * /bin/bash /home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile/packaging_cdr_script3.sh`?

Comment: i tried adding this but didn't work also `17 15 * * * root /bin/bash /home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile/packaging_cdr_script3.sh`

Comment: i tried adding this but didn't work also `17 15 * * * /bin/bash /home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile/packaging_cdr_script3.sh` and this time generated an empty file, just a tar without contents `drFEP1a:~/patrick_temp # ls -lhrt
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45 Jan 30 15:35 cdr_backup_20140130.tar.gz`

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: hi all the problem was that the `find` was working on the bad place, not it was working just adding this variable `LOCATION=/home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile/` and entering afterwards to this folder  `cd "${LOCATION}"`